# Placing trade in Heiken Ashi bars

Tags: pine-script

I am using pine script to write strategy using Heiken Ashi, every time I place a trade, I see the trade actually is placed at the beginning of the next bar instead of the end of current bar.. This is a big difference in Heiken Ashi as beginning of next bar is way below the end of current bar.

Answer (score 1):

It is not advised to run a strategy on HA as unrealistic results are sure to be found. Just as the close is a synthetic price, so is the open. They are averaged values that are unobtainable as far as real trade execution. In fact, it has a tendency to wildly boost the perceived performance of a strategy, which in real time will perform much different. Here is the equation for an HA candle set, and you will quickly see why they cant be trusted other than for trend interpretation.

```
haClose = (open + high + low + close) / 4
haOpen  = float(na)
haOpen := na(haOpen[1]) ? (open + close) / 2 : (nz(haOpen[1]) + nz(haClose[1])) / 2
haHigh  = max(high, max(haOpen, haClose))
haLow   = min(low,  min(haOpen, haClose))
```

Close and open are both averaged OHLC data of the current bar, or also incorporate data from the previous bar to smooth price action visually.

That said, there are things to consider in back testing to contemplate the problem you have described. in backtesting calculations are made on close, so the broker emulator will execute on next available chart data, which is the beginning of the next bar or open. This is not exclusive to Pine, this is generally speaking in regards to back testing. How can we enter if we don't know if something hasn't yet occurred? Historical data is OHLC - 4 data points. Typical calculations are done on the closing price of the bar, which is confirmed in history at one point. So once confirmed, we can take a trade, but that candle has closed!

Cheers my friend and best of luck

Answer (score 0):

if you want the script to execute the trade at the end of the current bar instead of at the next close there is an option in Strategy( ...,process_orders_on_close = true)